# MPI_ALLREDUCE fails using many cores

Tags: fortran, mpi, valgrind, openmpi

I have a code that I have checked using one core and it works perfectly. Even with valgrind I obtain no possible memory leaks. However, when the code (the module were it fails):

```
module m_solv3Dahv_dir_adj_all
  implicit none

  contains

  subroutine solv3Dahv_dir_adj_all( n_sg, shgat, buoy, cmpr, freq_0_inv, freq_inv, error_sum, grad_sum, illu_sum )
    use m_geo, only: nx, ny, nz
    implicit none
#ifdef mpi
      include 'mpif.h'
#endif
    integer, allocatable, intent(in) :: n_sg(:)
    type(shot_gather), allocatable, intent(inout) :: shgat(:)
    real(rl), intent(in) :: freq_0_inv, freq_inv
    real(rl), intent(out) :: error_sum
    real(rl), allocatable, intent(inout) :: grad_sum(:,:,:), illu_sum(:,:,:)
    real(rl), allocatable, intent(in)  :: cmpr(:,:,:), buoy(:,:,:)

    integer :: ix, iy, iz
    real(rl), allocatable :: v_aux(:)

    ...

    allocate( v_aux(nx), stat=stal ); if ( stal/=0 ) stop 'AE solv3Dahv_dir_adj_all 1'

    ...

#ifdef mpi
    ! Sum gradient for each process.
    do iy=1,ny
    do iz=1,nz
      v_aux = grad_sum(:,iy,iz)
      call MPI_ALLREDUCE( v_aux, grad_sum(:,iy,iz), nx, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr )
    end do
    end do
#endif

    ...
```

uses the MPI parts to sum the values of the allocatable `grad_sum`, it breaks with segmentation faults. I couldn't explain it, so I tested the code with valgrind and surprisingly the code runs up to the end (I have only reduce the number of iteration since otherwise it will never finish), but valgrind complains many times about the `MPI_ALLREDUCE`. I have copied bellow the first valgrind complain (there are hundreds but are all similar). I do not have idea of the problem, I guess it can be some problem related with MPI because the code runs when I use few cores (three), however, with 20 cores it breaks. The dimensions of grad_sum for the tests is small (nx=413, ny=351 and nz=1), so that it can not be a problem with the RAM. Is there any problem to send many MPI_ALLREDUCE inside a loop with many cores?

```
==32173== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==32173==    at 0x5421330: btl_openib_handle_incoming (btl_openib_component.c:3092)
==32173==    by 0x5422A0A: handle_wc (btl_openib_component.c:3401)
==32173==    by 0x5422A0A: poll_device (btl_openib_component.c:3541)
==32173==    by 0x5422A0A: progress_one_device (btl_openib_component.c:3649)
==32173==    by 0x5422A0A: btl_openib_component_progress (btl_openib_component.c:3674)
==32173==    by 0x557ADF9: opal_progress (opal_progress.c:207)
==32173==    by 0x53D53B4: opal_condition_wait (condition.h:99)
==32173==    by 0x53D53B4: ompi_request_default_wait_all (req_wait.c:263)
==32173==    by 0x543933E: ompi_coll_tuned_allreduce_intra_recursivedoubling (coll_tuned_allreduce.c:223)
==32173==    by 0x53E18FB: PMPI_Allreduce (pallreduce.c:105)
==32173==    by 0x5137D42: PMPI_ALLREDUCE (pallreduce_f.c:77)
==32173==    by 0x4F0CAF: __m_solv3dahv_dir_adj_all_MOD_solv3dahv_dir_adj_all (in /data/PROCESSED_DATA/dagnino/01-code/Nicaragua/inv_str2/fwi)
==32173==    by 0x504D03: __m_fwi_MOD_fwi (in /data/PROCESSED_DATA/dagnino/01-code/Nicaragua/inv_str2/fwi)
==32173==    by 0x50C44E: MAIN__ (in /data/PROCESSED_DATA/dagnino/01-code/Nicaragua/inv_str2/fwi)
==32173==    by 0x549EE9: main (in /data/PROCESSED_DATA/dagnino/01-code/Nicaragua/inv_str2/fwi)
==32173==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==32173==    at 0x4A05DBC: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:858)
==32173==    by 0x4A05E57: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:1021)
==32173==    by 0x54837B8: mca_mpool_rdma_alloc (mpool_rdma_module.c:103)
==32173==    by 0x53C0E9F: ompi_free_list_grow (ompi_free_list.c:203)
==32173==    by 0x541D088: prepare_device_for_use (btl_openib_component.c:1217)
==32173==    by 0x542096E: btl_openib_component_init (btl_openib_component.c:2902)
==32173==    by 0x5405E53: mca_btl_base_select (btl_base_select.c:111)
==32173==    by 0x5405191: mca_bml_r2_component_init (bml_r2_component.c:85)
==32173==    by 0x54039C8: mca_bml_base_init (bml_base_init.c:71)
==32173==    by 0x54A3CDF: mca_pml_ob1_component_init (pml_ob1_component.c:181)
==32173==    by 0x549CB73: mca_pml_base_select (pml_base_select.c:132)
==32173==    by 0x53D6219: ompi_mpi_init (ompi_mpi_init.c:522)
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code is incomplete. We can't really test it... See how to make a [mcve]. The usual advices apply, delete `include 'mpif.h'` and use `use mpi` instead. Try to enable all debugging flags you can (`-g -Wall -fcheck-all` or similar).

Comment: But the uninitialized value is reported to be created by `MPI_Init`, so it is an internal variable of OpenMPI, not your own variable. Probably a false positive, these are very common. We need to see the backtrace from the point where it crashes. This valgrind output may not show the right spot.

Comment: How is decleared the precision `rl`? If it is not `integer, parameter :: rl = REAL64` or `integer, parameter :: rl = selected_real_kind(15, 307)` as described in http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Real+precision , the floating point type may not be compatible with the use of `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION`.

Comment: `valgrind` can be run in an mpi-compatable way which will eliminate false positives from `MPI_INIT` and other routines. However, `valgrind` may not be able to find your problem even without the false positives. When I debug `MPI` issues, I typically end up doing the grunt work myself.

Comment: Thanks to all, I found the error. Just to leave the solution here, I detected the problem using the -check all (intel compiler). The code runs really slow but after eliminating some part I could use it. The error was not related to MPI_AllReduce nor the subroutine that gives the Valgrind errors. I did not defined a variable that for some reason only gives problem when I am using many cores, it something that I cannot explain but now it works.

Comment: That is exactly why you should always try to distill your problem down to a small self-contained code sample that compiles and reproduces the problem when run. It is called [mcve]. It removes other possible sources of error.